# I want left outer join data and right outer join data from Same table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my SQL stored procedure which is not returning any data when I am trying to do right outer join or left outer join.

```
DECLARE @testLeft TABLE (ID INT, SomeValue Uniqueidentifier)
DECLARE @testRight TABLE (ID INT, SomeOtherValue Uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO @testLeft (ID, SomeValue) 
VALUES
 (1, 'E32185F1-6237-434C-9C1B-EC7D694053EF')
,(2, '9DB48B93-535C-4A92-9FDF-F35627A2F759')
,(3, '33765811-958F-4B6C-A282-5F07E6AFEF5D')
,(4, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')

INSERT INTO @testRight (ID, SomeOtherValue) 
VALUES
 (1, 'E32185F1-6237-434C-9C1B-EC7D694053EF')
,(2, '9DB48B93-535C-4A92-9FDF-F35627A2F759')
,(3, '33765811-958F-4B6C-A282-5F07E6AFEF5D')
,(4, 'A0CCC809-5BC9-46DF-B6E7-F6D4040FAF5D')
,(5, '73B979EE-7EC7-4B4E-A930-15D5661DF75B')
,(6, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')

select * from @testLeft
select * from @testRight

SELECT 
    l.*
FROM 
    @testLeft l
INNER JOIN 
    @testRight r ON l.SomeValue = r.SomeOtherValue
WHERE 
    r.SomeOtherValue IS NULL
```

Comment: Will always return zero rows. (The ON clause is only true when r.SomeOtherValue is not null, but the where clause requires it to be null...)

Comment: Specify the expected result! (With that input data.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a full outer join? This query will match the data and return any values that don't match.

```
SELECT
l.SomeValue
,r.SomeOtherValue
FROM 
    @testLeft l
 FULL OUTER JOIN 
    @testRight r 
    ON 
        l.SomeValue = r.SomeOtherValue
WHERE r.SomeOtherValue IS NULL
OR l.SomeValue IS NULL
```

If this isn't what you're after then please provide a sample of your expected results and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you have `WHERE r.SomeOtherValue IS NULL` you are not getting any values. Get rid of `IS NULL` and the values that match from your table will appear.

```
SELECT 
    l.*
FROM 
    @testLeft l
INNER JOIN 
    @testRight r ON l.SomeValue = r.SomeOtherValue
```

Answer (score 0):

First should be apply to where clause then after to join table. so your query to first get only null record then join but did not getting result so it is empty.

```
SELECT l.*
FROM 
    @testLeft l
     FULL OUTER JOIN 
    @testRight r ON 
        l.SomeValue = r.SomeOtherValue
```